# Why does using vsprintf instead of sprintf to format a query string to pass to Laravel's DB::select cause the return of a non-object?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I am having trouble when using `vsprintf` instead of `sprintf` to format a query string I pass to `DB::select`. I have narrowed the problem down through elimination.
At first I attempted to use `sprintf` to insert a variable into a string. I used that string as a parameter for `DB::select`:

```
$query = sprintf("SELECT * FROM test_posts WHERE post_slug = %s;", $post_slug);
$result = DB::select($query);

dd($result);
```

The result was fine. I modified the code to allow inserting multiple variables into a string:

```
$table = 'test_posts';
$column = 'post_slug';
$query = vsprintf("SELECT * FROM %s WHERE %s = '%s';", [$table, $column, $identifier_slug]);
$rslt_post = DB::select($query);

//return view('post_viewer', ['arr_post' => $rslt_post] );

echo "<pre>";
print_r($rslt_post);        
dd($rslt_post);
```

The result was fine and identical for both code variants:

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [post_ctr] => 2
            [post_slug] => my-first-post
            [posted_by] => J_Rives
            [date_posted] => 2020-02-03 09:03
            [last_edit] => 2020-02-03 16:54
            [post_body] => Test post #2. Ctr = 2, No title.
        )

)
array:1 [▼
  0 => {#250 ▶}
]
```

I attempted to return a view with the result object passed as a parameter.

`return view('post_viewer', ['arr_post' => $rslt_post] );`

The result was the following error message:

```
Facade\Ignition\Exceptions\ViewException
Trying to get property 'posted_by' of non-object (View: C:\Users\7\testproject1.0\resources\views\post_viewer.blade.php)
http://127.0.0.1:8000/posts/my-first-post
```

The referenced line in `post_viewer.blade.php` is this: 
 `<h4> {{ $arr_post->posted_by }} </h4>`.

Why does it claim that a variable verified by `dd` and `print_r` as an array object is a "non-object"  from which I attempted to access the "property" called "title"?

Comment: Your `$arr_post` is an array. `$arr_post[0]->posted_by` should be fine

Comment: Thanks. Will take note and try this one too. Still, do you know why `vsprintf` causes this effect? Is it also just the fact that `vsprintf` is fine and it's something in my test project that is the root cause of the error?

Comment: Can you share more details about how `vsprintf` is related here? The return value of an executed database query should be absolutely the same if the query is the same

Comment: Why are you using Laravel? Isn't it so you can do things like `TestPost::where('post_slug', $post_slug)->get();`???

Comment: @NicoHaase Yes, that's what I thought. When I use `sprintf` it returns an object but `vsprintf` it seems to return either a "non-object" - according to the error message - or an array as said in the comments below. The question is, why? Why is `vsprintf` causing a different result for the same query?

Comment: @miken32 Yes, I am just curios. I will try out the suggested use of DB::table etc. The reason for the error might be helpful in the future. Also, who knows if I 
 can't sidestep this issue in some edge case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

no need of `sprintf` or `vsprintf`

```
$result = DB::select("SELECT * FROM test_posts WHERE post_slug = :slug", ['slug' => $post_slug]);
```

and fully dynamic

```
$names = ['test_posts', 'comments'];
$columns = ['post_slug', 'comment_slug'];
foreach($names as $i => $tableName){
     $rslt_post = DB::table($tableName)->where($columns[$i], $identifier_slug);
}
```

Comment: Isn't there supposed to be a comma between `'post_slug'` and `'comment_slug'`? Thanks for giving that info. I will also supplement this answer with the notes I read in the docs. Still, why does this error occur? I managed to solve the problem but still want to know why `vsprintf` caused an error even though it returns a string just like `sprintf`.

Comment: @JoachimRives updated the code ya, I am also not sure why does this happen as both return string only...